# Oracle ADF Mobile Taskflow

Tags: mobile, oracle-adf

I am working on Oracle ADF Mobile application.

In application, First screen is the Login Screen. On the successful login, I have to redirect the user to the second screen.

I am not getting how to redirect the Login Screen (**view**) to the Second screen (**view**) only on the successful login?

Which condition I should have to write for **Control Flow Case**?

Please help. Thanks in advance...:)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you first run through the ADF Mobile tutorial here:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18941_01/tutorials/buildmobileappscontent/adfmobiletutorial_1.html
Basically in your taskflow you give the flow a name, and then in your page's button you associate the action property with that flow name.

Answer (score 0):

First go through the following tutorial.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18941_01/tutorials/jdtut_11r2_57/jdtut_11r2_57.html

To redirect the Login Screen (view) to the Second screen (view) only on the successful login you have to use Router Component.

Enjoy learning.